# How to use AppKit WKWebView in a Mac Catalyst App?

Tags: swift, uikit, wkwebview, appkit, mac-catalyst

I'm working on a **Mac Catalyst** App and using a `WKWebView` there. I found lots of issue in the behaviour of `WKWebView` like text selection issue, copy paste issue etc.

To check if it is related to `WKWebView` I created a Mac App project and created a `WKWebView` there by importing ***AppKit*** **WebKit** and didn't found any issue mentioned above.

So as per my knowledge there is some difference in **UIKit -> WebKit -> WKWebView** and **AppKit -> WebKit -> WKWebView**.

How can I use AppKit's WebKit in my UIKit Mac Catalyst App ?